# Portulacas (moss rose) bloom for 1 day then wither?

Tags: flowers

To my understanding, they are suppose to bloom longer than 1 day. Each stem has 2 to 3 buds on top and each opens on different days but each one opens for 1 day, closes in the afternoon then withers and starts seeding. I don't understand? And also they look like the kind that are suppose to have more than 1 row of petals (that's what the seed packet looks like)  and mine only have 1 row of petals.

Comment: *Portulaca grandiflora* only has single flowers (one row of petals). There are other varieties with double flowers. I guess either the picture was wrong, the packet contained the wrong seeds, or you didn't buy what you hoped you were buying.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why they are withering after 1 day?

Comment: The flowers begin dying as soon as they're pollinated, so you have some busy bees in your garden. This explains the one-day-and-done behavior you're experiencing.